# Pandas vectorization to assign column value based on date, given another dataframe with value and start date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, vectorization

In Pandas, I have a dataframe `df1` with stocks investments and a start date:

```
Stock,StartDate,Investment
A,2022-01-01,100
A,2022-02-01,150
B,2022-01-01,90
B,2022-01-15,100
...
```

Then I have a `df2`:

```
Stock,Date
A,2022-01-01
A,2022-01-02
A,2022-01-05
...
B,2022-01-01
...
```

I want to add a column `Investment` to `df2` filled with investment taken from `df1`: given a date `d` and a stock `S` in `df2`, I want to assign the investment in `df1` such date `d` >= `StartDate` and `d < next start date`.

Expected output (`df2`) in this case is:

```
Stock,Date,Investment
A,2022-01-01,100
A,2022-01-02,100
A,2022-01-05,100
...
A,2022-01-31,100
A,2022-02-01,150
A,2022-02-02,150
...
B,2022-01-01,90
B,2022-01-02,90
...
B,2022-01-14,90
B,2022-01-15,100
B,2022-01-16,100
...
```

This can clearly be done with a loop, but I was looking for a more efficient approach, possibly using vectorization.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (df1)
    a          b    c
0  A 2022-01-01  100
1  A 2022-02-01  150
2  B 2022-01-01   90
3  B 2022-01-15  100

    
print (df2)
    a          b
0  A 2022-01-01
1  A 2022-01-02
2  A 2022-01-05
3  B 2022-01-01

df = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('b'), df1.sort_values('b'), on='b', by='a')
print (df)
   a          b    c
0  A 2022-01-01  100
1  B 2022-01-01   90
2  A 2022-01-02  100
3  A 2022-01-05  100
```